# More than one criteria is met for an altered arte

Tags: tales-of-vesperia

Let's take the example Rita and her skill Splash.
It changes to aqua laser with the dispersion skill active and also changes to freeze lancer with gale and chain skills active.

Is there a way to consistently get freeze lancer if I have all 3 of these skills active or is it randomized which skill Splash changes to?

```
Aqua Laser       | Splash - Dispersion

Freeze Lancer    | Splash - Gale, Chain
```